# about auto release in Xcode 4.3

Tags: objective-c, xcode, autorelease

Hi I'm new to objective C. 
In the old version of Xcode, when we create new project the IDE generate NSAutoreleasePool object like below to allow auto release an object

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
        NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

        [pool drain]; 
        return 0; }
```

However in the Xcode 4.3, the IDE generate the below code

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])

{

    @autoreleasepool {
          //insert code

    }
    return 0; 
}
```

With the older version .. i could manually release the object .. With the new Xcode 4.3 when i tried release the object but the release function is crossed out ... Why is that...?

Thank you.

Comment: Your project is probably ARC enabled. If so, you don't need to release anything, the system will do it for you.

Comment: Someone else is now taking the burden of releasing your objects. You should feel better with it. There are a lot of other new features, like ARC. See your xcode release notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) is enables in your project. In ARC, reference count operations (ex. release) on objects are not allowed. The red line through "release" simply means that the method is deprecated, or no longer needed. The system will release everything for you.

Comment: Thank you all very much ...This is a very good news.. hope C compiler will do this as well .. :D

Answer (score 3):

New projects have ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) enabled by default. In ARC, reference count operations on objc objects are forbidden.

There should be an option in the New Project sequence to use manual reference counting or GC.